# Getting the screen location of a CollectionView cell from a UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, frame

I have a `ViewController` with a `UITableView`
And in each cells of this tableView, I have a `UICollectionView`.

I would like to get the screen location of a cell of my UICollectionView.

[image]

I've followed [this](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) tutorial to build the view:

Comment: you can use    `let attributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
        let rect = attributes?.frame` This will give you the frame at a particular indexpath

Comment: Thanks but this give me the frame inside the tableViewCell. But I need to know the cell's frame inside the entire screen

Comment: try this `let centreWithMainView = collectionView.convertPoint(cell.center, toView: collectionView.superview)`

Comment: or `let frame = cell.convert(cell.frame, to: cell.superview?.superview)`

Comment: It's almost the same thing as your first response. I've already tried this and it can't work because the collectionView doesn't have viewController as superview :/

Comment: Then you need to do  `cell.superview?.superview` and may be more. or have a for loop till it gives you required superview, something like `while superView != self.view` and then getting the frame

Comment: haha ok I get it! You were right to go deeper in the superview!
I found it with : `let realCenter = collectionView.convert(cell.frame, to: collectionView.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview)` (swift 4.2)
Thank you @Shruti

Comment: your welcome. i wrote the answer.  please accept the same  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `point` of your `cell` by using:

```
let realCenter = collectionView.convert(cell.frame, to: collectionView.superview)
```

But if this will give you with respect to the `collectionView`. If you need to find the centre with respect to `main view`, you need to go through all the `superview`.

```
let realCenter = collectionView.convert(cell.frame, to: collectionView.superview?.superview?.superview?.superview)
```

`loop` through the views to find your `superview` you are looking for and then find the `frame`